# FFMPEG 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, ffmpeg

```
$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i temp/'.$temp_name.' -i watermark/watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w-10):y=(main_h-overlay_h-10)" -codec:a copy videos/'.$filename;
system($cmd);
```

On my bluehost dedicated server this command is working for small size(~900kb) videos but when I upload big size(~8MB) video then I get 500 Internal Server Error. It works fine on my local machine. 
ffmpeg version on server is 2.2.4
php version on server is 5.4.22
Please guide me.

Comment: what do you mean by arbitrary local processes ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad: you are not using a hosting service, nbut a dedicated system! Sorry!

Comment: I also tried exec() but same issue

Comment: Sure. Both commands do the same, except for result processing.

Comment: Since it is your system you should be able to take a look into the log files.

Comment: then how is it working for small size files ?

Comment: You might hit some limit of resources. Like available memory.

Answer (score 0):

Check this if this helps you. It is working and creating flv files for me.

```
$dir = "YOUR_DIR_PATH";
$command = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '" . $dir . $file . "' -an -ss 00:00:03 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -y '" .  $dir . str_replace(".flv", ".jpg'", $file) . ";";
    mail("testemail@gmail.com","test flv to image ",$command);// Send Email to check command(Optional)
    echo exec("$command");
```